# calculation in css variable is not working

Tags: css

I wrote the following code in css. The purpose of the first line is to calculate the number of objects that can fit in one line based on the screen width and that calculated number is used in the second line to calculate the width of these objects.

```
:root{
--linkCount: calc(100vw / 200px);
--linkwidth: calc(230px + (100vw - 60px - (var(--linkCount) * (230px + 6px))) / var(--linkCount));
}
```

The problem is that the first calculation `calc(100vw / 200px);` is not working. When I run this code on the website, the objects have the smallest width possible based the content (so basically `width:auto;`) When I replace it with e.g. `calc(5);` or `5;` it works. I already tried removing or adding spacing but no luck.

#### edit 1

Here a code snippet. The two variable are placed in the `:root`
https://jsfiddle.net/josvm9dw/

Can somebody explain to me why it is not working because I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
When it comes to multiplication and division you don't need to specify the unit, because it's just not needed

```
calc(100vw * 5px)
```

Why `px` specifically all we want is to multiplay the first value by 5, And same goes for division.

However you can `add` and `subtract` other units together.

**demo**

```css
div {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color:white;
}
/* At least one must be a number */
div:nth-child(1) {
  width: calc(100px * 3);
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(100vw * 50vh);
}


/* the right side must be a number */
div:nth-child(3) {
  width: calc(300px / 2);
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  width: calc(2 / 200px);
}

/* both can be units */

div:nth-child(5) {
  width: calc(200px + 3em);
}

div:nth-child(6) {
  width: calc(100px + 10vh);
}

div:nth-child(7) {
  width: calc(200px - 20pt);
}

div:nth-child(8) {
  width: calc(100vw - 50vh);
}
```

```html
<div>calc(100px * 3);</div>
<div>calc(100vw * 50vh); Invalid treated as auto(default)</div>

<div>calc(300px / 2);</div>
<div>calc(2 / 200px); Invalid treated as auto(default)</div>

<div>calc(200px + 3em);</div>
<div>calc(100px + 10vh);</div>
<div>calc(200px - 20pt);</div>
<div>calc(100vw - 50vh);</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not working, not even `calc(800px / 200);`which should result 4

Comment: @Vinc199789 Can you provide a code snippet reproducing the issue ?

Comment: I added a code snipped in the original question

Comment: The issue is that your second calc `--linkwidth:` is not following the rules, `var(--linkCount)` that will return a value with pixels as the unit and as mentioned before you can't use units in multiplication and division. to fix this remove units from your first `--linkCount: calc(800 / 200);`

Comment: That works, but do I get it working with the `100vw` because I want the 800 to be replaced by the screen width.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you can get calc to output a value without a unit, i suggest that you rethink your math with regards to the rules

Comment: Alright then. Thanks for your help, I will try to find another way. I want to avoid using JS because of the loading speed. I will share it here if I found a valid css solution

Comment: I'm guessing it can be done, if you can find a way to leave the unit last

Answer (score 3):

You can't divide `vw` by `px`, they're different units of measurement. Divide only by absolute numbers:

```
--linkCount: calc(100vw / 200);
```

Use `200` or however much you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not working. `calc(800px / 200);` is also not working as a test